# Saving with a Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have a macro in Excel that allows me to select the file I wish to open and then runs a rounding formula on column 'D', copies and pastes the data from columns A,B and D into a new sheet, puts that into a new workbook and then opens the save as window to allow the rounded data to be saved as a separate document. However, is there a way for the macro to automatically save the file out, using the same file name that was opened originally and just add  _truncated to the end of it?

For example, if i open a file called Data 111111.xyz could i write the macro to save it out as Data 111111_truncated.xyz

The names of the files that are opened are different each time.

The macro I currently have is as follows:

```
Sub SortRoundandSave()
'
' SortRoundandSave Macro
' This macro will sort, Round and save your data
'
Dim workSht As Worksheet: Set workSht = ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("") ' Enter the name of sheet

Dim FilePath As String
Dim strLine As String
Dim rowCnt As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select the file"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add Description:="Text Files", Extensions:="*.xyz"
    .InitialFileName = "Drive:\File path\File path\File path\File path\File path\xxx.xyz"
    If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
    FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

rowCnt = 1

Open FilePath For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strLine
        workSht.Cells(rowCnt, 1) = strLine
        rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
    Loop
Close #1


With workSht
    Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowCnt - 1, 1)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), 
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
                            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), 
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("A:A,B:B,D:D").Select
Range("D1").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Rounded Data").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Truncated Data").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Truncated Data").Move
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas